# Throw 404 from shows / lists

Tags: couchdb

I query the view like this:

```
/db/_design/myviewname/_view/foo?key=%22ABC123%22
```

The result is the following:

```
{
 total_rows: 3,
 offset: 3,
 rows: [ ]
}
```

All good.

Since no doc was found I'd like to throw a 404 from a show or list.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List/#Sending_a_Redirect), you can issue redirect responses via Show/List functions. As such, it is also possible to send out arbitrary HTTP status codes. (like 404)

```
function (head, req) {
    start({ code: 404 });
}
```

Comment: I can't get the return variant to work. Chrome says ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING. curl: "curl: (56) Received problem 2 in the chunky parser".

Comment: Maybe with a `return`, you need to also specify a `body`. (even if it's just a `null` or `""`) Does that change anything?

Comment: Is seams that it's simply no longer supported in Couch > 0.10 http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List/#Sending_a_Redirect

You might want to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if *404* would be the right choice here. It really means *not found*.

From the W3 HTTP/1.1 [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html):

> #### [10.4.5 404 Not Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5)
>
> > The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

There is another more appropriate response status code I think. *204 No Content* which sounds more like what you really want to tell the client.

> #### [10.2.5 204 No Content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5)
>
> > The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.
> >
> > If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.
> >
> > The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Now to set a custom response header you simply specify it in the object passed to the start function, like this.

```js
function(head, req) {
  return { "code": 204 };
}
```