# How to throw (e.g.) 404 from list depending on number of rows

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to fire a 404 from a list. Something like this:

```
function (head, req) {
    var row;
    var returnArr = [];
    while (row = getRow()) {
        returnArr.push(row.value);
    }
    if(returnArr.length === 0) {
        start({code:404});
        send(JSON.stringify({error:"not found"}));
    } else {
        send(JSON.stringify(returnArr));
    }
};
```

I found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846050/throw-404-from-shows-lists). However, is seams that I'm calling the `start()` function to late. When the `start()` function is right at the beginning (in the first line) it works.

Of course I can not call `start()` earlier, since I first have to determine if the view has any rows.

How to implement this?

**UPDATE:**

It indeed seams that start() does not work after getRow() is called. Not sure if this is an expected behavior. Also this doesn't work either:

```
function (head, req) {
    var row;
    var returnArr = [];
    while (row = getRow()) {
        returnArr.push(row.value);
    }
    if(returnArr.length === 0) {
        throw (['error', 'not_found', 'Some message like Page not found']);
    } else {
        send(JSON.stringify(returnArr));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is an open bug. Unfortunately Jira is down so I can't link to the issue. But it is as you found, you cant currently call getRow() before start().

Comment: Confirmed, here it is: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-514

And the waiting pull request: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/18